# Are Google documents URLs permanent?

Tags: google-drive

I like using Google documents but I want to be able to tag my documents properly (without using a hierarchy structure)

My plan is to create the documents in Google docs and then link to them in Delicious. The URLs seem to contain a string of characters that look something like a GUID. Does anyone know if these are guaranteed not to change and if not how I can achieve the effect I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this Google help entry](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182144), it would seem the urls are permanent until you [reset them](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=182145)

Comment: Thanks, I've got them in delicious and everything seems to be working fine

Comment: At this time there is no way to reset the permanent URL of Google Drive files. See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45688/how-to-reset-a-google-document-sharing-link

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Yes, file and folders URLs obtained through the sharing feature of Google Drive and Google editor's files are permanent.

## Explanation

Google Drive and Google editor's files have assigned a permanent URL including a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) usually referred in Google's documentation as file-id or folder-id.

### Remarks

For folders, the browser web address could include the folder structure but it's not required for sharing folders.

URLs of web site files hosted in Google Drive could include the folder structure from the web site root folder.

By the other hand, download file and folders URLs got through right click > copy link address or other similar means are not permanent.

## References

- [How to share - Google Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en)

Answer (score -1):

Based on the feature to [share documents with 'anyone with the link](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=180199)' the Google Docs links look to be stable (unless the owner chooses to reset them).

Alternatively, you can create the links using the Google Docs viewer: http://docs.google.com/viewer

Comment: I don't want to create a new public link just to have a link to my documents that wont change so I can navigate to to them externally

I don't exactly understand what the page you posted the 'viewer' link about does

Comment: At this time there is no way to reset the permanent URL of Google Drive files. See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45688/how-to-reset-a-google-document-sharing-link