# How to reset a Google document sharing link

Tags: google-drive, sharing, google-docs

I have set the sharing permission for a file in Google Drive to *Anyone who has the link can view*.

However, while I still want to be able to share this file, **I want to generate a new link and revoke the previous one**.

I remember it used to be possible, but I can't find the *Reset link* option anywhere: making the document private and sharing it again seems to generate the same URL.

Any idea?

Answer (score 15):

If you need a new link created, you can right-click on the file and **Make a copy** of it. When you then go to **Share** it you'll get a new link.

[image]

Comment: That's a nice workaround! (A bit cumbersome though :/)

Comment: In addition to Mr. Lott's useful workaround to create a new link for your document, it is important to note that, in order to **"Revoke the previous [link]"** as you'd asked, you send the original document to the trash, and also go to gDrive's [Trash] folder and permanently delete the old file 'forever' - until it is permanently deleted, recipients of the link to the old file can still access and make copies of the document.

Answer (score -1):

I believe another way would to create a folder outside the shared folder or file, and transfer the file(s) or folder(s) to that newly created folder. Google Drive will then warn that the links will be reset and previous links will not work anymore. This way you don't have to duplicate the files (Fills up space) and you keep the folder structure.

Comment: Google Drive doesn't reset the links when a file is moved from one folder to another.

Comment: I just tried and the link remains the same.

Answer (score -1):

My method only works if you have shared Drives (a commercial Google workspace account):  Moving the file or folder between personal and shared space breaks the old share links and the new link is different when re-shared.